# How to deploy a pure Angular application from Visual Studio Team System to Azure websites

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

Does anyone know how to deploy a pure Angular application to Azure websites?

I have a Angular 2 application (like the Angular 2 Quick Start) in VSTS Git source control. How can I deploy the application to Azure websites from setting up the VSTS build?

I saw document for deploying node.js (with angular) to Azure: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/azure/nodejs. I did successfully deploy many of my angular applications to Azure websites following the instructions in the document. But I don't use anything with node.js in my Angular application. I hope that I can just deploy my pure Angular application to azure websites.

Previously, I used Visual Studio to create empty project to contain my Angular application. These kind of projects can be easily deployed to Azure websites. Now I am using VS code and I don't want to create any Visual Studio Solution. I don't know how to setup a continuous deployment in VSTS with just the pure Angular code.

I know I probably need to use IIS anyway and I need some settings/configs. But I just don't want to do them in Visual Studio project.

Answer (score -1):

Using node.js to create a deploy package and then deploying the package by "Azure Web App Deployment" task is a convenient way to deploy to Azure Site.

However, if you don't like this, you can create a batch/power-shell script to copy your deployment files in Azure Web App via FTP method. Refer to this link for details: [Deploy by copying files to Azure manually](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#ftp)

And you can also try to deploy it from Source Control directly: [Deploy from a cloud-based source control service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-deploy/#deploy-from-a-cloud-based-source-control-service)