# How to setup a build+deploy environment for an angularjs/asp.net web api?

Tags: angularjs, tfs, asp.net-web-api2, bitbucket-server

I have an angularjs app with a c# webapi . The repo for the angular app is stash and the c# restapi is in TFS. Is it possible/easy to create an automated build and deployment environment for this stack? What are possible solutions for this? Does anyone have a blogpost abt. this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way to integrate with Bitbucket repo and TFS for now:

- Option 1: One-Time import of source code form Bitbucket
- Option 2: Stick with Bitbucket and trigger CI on VSTS/TFS

Note it's not a real CI

> While this is not exactl what some people might expect from CI
>   (because it doesn’t really build on every check-in) for most scenarios
>   this should be good enough. Especially if your build process is
>   running for a longer time this shouldn’t be an issue at all.

Details please refer this tutorial:  [Integrating VSTS with Bitbucket](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dmx/2016/10/13/integrating-vsts-with-bitbucket/), you could also take a look at this blog: [Visual Studio Team Services: Connecting a BitBucket Repository](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34313.visual-studio-team-services-connecting-a-bitbucket-repository.aspx)

For the CI/CD of angular app/angularjs/asp.net web api, even though there is not a blog full described everything. You still could refer some similar related blogs(even for Azure) and setup your own pipeline, use **NPM** to install packages/dependencies:

- [Setting up a CI pipeline for deploying your Angular application to
  Azure using Visual Studio Team Services and GitHub](https://medium.com/@flu.lund/setting-up-a-ci-pipeline-for-deploying-your-angular-application-to-azure-using-visual-studio-team-f686c8f190cf)
- [Define a continuous integration build for your Node.js app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/archive/apps/nodejs/nodejs-to-azure)
- [How to deploy a pure Angular application from Visual Studio Team System to Azure websites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35823008/how-to-deploy-a-pure-angular-application-from-visual-studio-team-system-to-azure)